# Biostar K8M800 AM2 motherboard doesn't detect SATA HDD

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, sata

I have an old Biostar K8M800 AM2 motherboard, and I can't seem to get it to detect a SATA hard drive.

It boots just fine from an IDE drive, but the BIOS simply does not see the SATA Seagate hard drive that I'm trying to get it to boot from. (I have verified the drive is fine using another computer)

I downloaded the PDF manual to see if there is a jumper I have to set on the board to enable the SATA ports or something, but I wasn't able to find anything.

I also ran across [this unsolved thread from 2005](https://hardforum.com/threads/k8m800-chipset-doesnt-see-sata-drives.889546/), where the OP has the same issue.

Any ideas as to why the BIOS doesn't see it?

Comment: Are you using the current firmware?  What size is the SATA drive?  The controller might only support specific sizes below a specific size.  We need more information.

Comment: @Ramhound I have updated to the latest BIOS. The hard drive is 1TB

Comment: GPT or MBR?  Your motherboard only supports MBR partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound Should that really matter? The BIOS should still be able to tell the drive is there even if it can't boot from it, no?

Comment: It *should* not matter. However it *has* mattered i n he past.

Comment: I tried it with both a drive with an MBR table and a drive with a GPT table. Still nothing

Comment: @Ramhound I also tried using the jumper on the SATA drive to restrict it to SATA 1 speeds, still no dice :\

Comment: @AndroidDev - "Should that really matter?" - It matters if you are trying to install Windows.  Since the HDD is not being listed, an HDD with an EFI partition, would not show up in a system that wasn't using UEFI which your machine does have.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying to install Linux actually. And I tried both with a drive that has MBR partitioning and a drive that has GPT. The problem is not installing an OS. The problem is getting the BIOS to even realize that a HDD is present

Comment: Have you tried booting into the installation environment, to verify, the drive actually is not detected?

Comment: @Ramhound I have not. I suppose I can try that, but even if the installer is able to detect and install the OS, it would be pointless since the BIOS wouldn't be able to boot it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the SATA controller is enabled (and not RAID).
Note that RAID mode is the default configuration in that BIOS.

**K8M800 Micro AM2 BIOS Setup**
from ftp://ftp.biostar-usa.com/manuals/K8M800MAM2/K8M800%20Micro%20AM2bios.pdf

> **OnChip SATA**
>       This option allows you to enable the onchip Serial ATA.
>       The Choices: **Enabled** (default), Disabled.
>
> **SATA Mode**
>       This option allows you to select SATA Mode.
>       The Choices: IDE, **RAID** (default)

BTW that mobo only has SATA 1.0 ports.

Comment: ***facepalm*** I couldn't find anything about SATA in the BIOS, but I went into every single menu and sub menu and eventually I found it... sure enough, it was disabled.