# My hard disk spins but cannot be seen internally; it is fine externally. What is wrong and is it fixable?

Tags: hard-drive

Windows 7; ASUS G73Jh laptop.

The internal hard disk spins but will not boot the computer. BIOS does not see it. When I put it in an external drive case and boot the computer with the System Recovery Disk, I can see the disk and the files on it fine via the Command Prompt (dir d:, for example).

When I put it back in the laptop, it booted once OK but all other attempts have the BIOS showing no hard disk.

What is wrong and is it possible to fix the problem practically?

Comment: It may not even be a configuration option on a laptop, but check anyway that the SATA port(s) are enabled.  E.G. https://superuser.com/questions/1226432/biostar-k8m800-am2-motherboard-doesnt-detect-sata-hdd  When did problem start to occur, i.e. randomly one day or after you replaced something?

Comment: Thanks, but I went through all the BIOS settings before posting. I only have a choice between AHCI and IDE, and it is set to AHCI. I did try IDE, which did not do anything, as expected, so I switched back to AHCI. Since your posting, I did recheck BIOS just in case, but it was as I remembered. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You didn't answer my question regarding how this issue started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds suspiciously like a harddrive that is about to die.
It takes much longer than normal to do it's initialization when booting, so it isn't ready yet when Bios does its harddrive detection routine. (And because Bios doesn't see it, it won't boot.)

When you connect it externally it has much longer to power-up, so by the time your alternative OS has done starting up and starts looking for additional disks (the Bios isn't used in this case) the drive is finally "awake" and usable.

Chances are that if you leave the drive inside the laptop and boot the computer normally it wont work on the first boot attempt, but if you leave the laptop running and then reboot (without shutting down/powercycling the laptop) it may be possible to boot on a second (or third) attempt.

To verify it is really the disk and not a problem with the laptop itself put another drive in the laptop and see if the Bios can see it. 
If the laptop won't recognize another disk the laptop is broken and most likely needs a new motherboard. (In that case I hope for you it is still under warranty. That is a very expensive repair.)

If the laptop can see the other disk the laptop itself is fine, but your harddrive is most likely dying.
As an additional check you can hook it up, as external drive, to another computer and run CrystalDiskInfo or another utility that can read SMART figures from the drive to analyze the SMART data.

**Anyway: Get your important files of that harddrive ASAP while it is still working as an external drive! It can go from partially dead to 100% dead at any time. I would even recommend to save your files FIRST and only afterwards do any further experiments.**

Comment: I also thought the HD was dying so I got another and restored a Windows image of the first drive on it. The same situation happens to BOTH drives: they spin up internally but BIOS does not see them. I can see both of them when mounted externally and they are both fine.

Comment: I am wondering if the SATA controlled in the laptop is causing the problem, but I don't know much about these. Could it be a loose connection from the controller to the motherboard (if this even makes sense)? If the controller is bad, can it be replaced in the laptop easily? Cheaply? Or is it likely something else wrong?

Comment: Sata is integrated in the chipset. If it is broken the entire motherboard needs to be replaced. But.... are you sure you didn't accidentally change sata settings in the bios? You could do a "reset to bios defaults".

Comment: I checked the BIOS settings. As I comment elsewhere, I only have a choice between AHCI and IDE, and it is set to AHCI. I did try IDE, which did not do anything, as expected, so I switched back to AHCI. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: NEW: In recent experiments, I have been able to get the hard drive to work sometimes by partially inserting it into the controller rather than inserting it all the way in. If it is all the way in, the drive is not seen. If I find the "sweet spot" by juggling it around until it is not fully inserted but still sufficiently in contact, I can sometimes get the computer to boot and to run for a extended period (an hour or more). On five attempts, two eventually ended with the blue screen saying the computer shut down to avoid damage, while three attempts I did full sessions and shut down naturally.

Comment: @jma7777 *"...by partially inserting it into the controller"* -- You probably mean the connector, not the *"controller"*.  Connectors are a common point of failure.  They can be damaged.  The electrical contacts can oxidize or even corrode.  Skin oils (e.g. fingerprints) by touching can lead to contacts failing.  The faulty connector could be on the male/HDD side or the female/motherboard side.